# Install process for phpseclib 2.0 not working

Tags: php, phpseclib

When installing phpseclib-2.0 the composer does not seem to create the correct directory structure

I am trying to install phpseclib-2.0 on my production linux server. I have 1.07 installed an working on another but want to bring the production server up to 2.0.
The steps I followed to install are:
1.) I downloaded and extracted the library to phpseclib-2.0/
2.) Copied that folder to vendor/ in my application folder
3.) cd to vendor/phpseclib-2.0
4.) execute composer install

The resulting structure is 
vendor - phpseclib-2.0
vendor - phpseclib-2.0 - phpseclib (includes Crypt, File, Math, Net, System)
vendor - phpseclib-2.0 - vendor (this is where composer and autloaded ended up)

This is the code I use for testing:

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/phpseclib-2.0/vendor/autoload.php';
use phpseclib\Net\SFTP;

$connection = ssh2_connect($FTP_URI, 22);
if (!$ssh->login(username, password)) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $ssh->exec('pwd');
echo $ssh->exec('ls -la');
```

I expect it to give me a directory listing.

What I get is:
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function ssh2_connect()

Note the test is run with: php -f sshtest.php

Thanks for your help

Comment: I think you might need to also `use phpseclib\Net\SSH2`

Comment: Also, it might be better installation practice to go to your application root and simply run `composer require phpseclib/phpseclib:~2.0` . This should put phpseclib-2.0 in your root /vendor/ directory with the proper structure. It also updates your root `composer.json` file to make sure other dependencies remain in sync. Then you can just `require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';`

Answer (score 0):

```
$connection = ssh2_connect($FTP_URI, 22);
```

That's not defined in phpseclib. That's PECL's ssh2 extension.

Here's what you need to do to make this work with phpseclib:

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/phpseclib-2.0/vendor/autoload.php';
use phpseclib\Net\SFTP;

$connection = new SFTP($FTP_URI, 22);
if (!$ssh->login(username, password)) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $ssh->exec('pwd');
echo $ssh->exec('ls -la');
```

Comment: Thank you.  I was thinking there was something missing.  I made the change and got back "Class 'phpseclib\Net\SFTP' not found".  Since a lot of the code being ported already uses the ssh2_connect protocol I think I am going to install the PECL  ssh2 extension.  Hopefully that will solve the issue.